# Smart Search by Fields of Page Type

Tags: search, content-management-system, kentico

We have a page type which contains fields as follows: **Name**, **Title**, **SubmittedDate**. So, on the UI, we need to enable search by each of the field columns in this page type including **From** and **To** date for **SubmittedDate**. We created a search index but it only searches the text data/content. So, how to filter search results by each individual fields?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select which fields are indexed on the page type. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/creating-search-indexes/defining-page-indexes#Definingpageindexes-Configuringsearchsettingsforpagefields)

Comment: I have already indexed all the fields in page type, but don't know how to query it from UI on form submit or through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

TO search by particular field use following syntax:

```
<field code name>:<searched phrase>
```

The field should be configured as searchable.

Field searching allows users to define additional conditions in search expressions. All conditions must start with either the + or - symbol. The + symbol indicates that only results which fulfill the field condition should be returned. The - symbol has the opposite meaning, only results that do not contain the specified value in the given field are retrieved.

For example:

```
+network +NewsReleaseDate:[20080101 TO 20091231]
```

When searching for this expression using a page index, the smart search returns only news pages containing the word network, released in the year 2008 or 2009.

See more details [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/smart-search-syntax).

Comment: But, how to pass From and To dates from search form??

Comment: It looks like you might need to implement custom search filters in order to implement functionality you're looking for.